# How to get rid of wrapping '\n' getting $(element).html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

When I get `$(eventObject.target).parent.html()` I receive such string

```
'\n    <img alt="" src="/..." ">\n  '
```

while I need only

```
'<img alt="" src="/..." ">'
```

How to get that right way or how to clean html from '\n' and spaces?

ps

target is an image inside a div

Comment: `eventObject.target.outerHTML.trim().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g,'');`

Comment: `.html()` is just a wrapper for the browser native `innerHTML` property, so it's quite browser dependent. Does the original html/document source have the line return in it by chance? My guess is that you're getting the literal text value between the opening and closing tags. Or you could regex the whole mess down, like adeneo suggests :-)

Comment: I get html from haml parser, and I want to leave it as is. Thank you, adeneo and Patrick M! I'll regex the whole mess down )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) jQuery parent is a method:

```
$(eventObject.target).parent().html();
```

2) You can clean the spaces this way:

```
$(eventObject.target).parent().html().replace(/\s|\n|\r/g, '');
```

Comment: not quite correct regex, I came to /\n\s+|\s+\n/g, but I get it, thank you, Samuel Liew!

Comment: `\s` deletes all spaces inside `<img ...>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
 $(eventObject.target).parent().html().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

Comment: I voted up, but marked as the solution the first answer.Thank you, Sankalp Mishra!